# Volley does not return any value, if I use the url in the browser it does return values, android studio

Tags: java, android, wordpress, android-volley, response

I am using volley to extract the categories and posts from a wordpress site to display them in an android application, first the categories respond well to me, while I am adding the categories to a list, I am trying to extract the posts for another list, but it returns [], I use the url in the browser and it returns the values ok, help me, what am I doing wrong?

```
    public void extractCategories() { String URL = getResources().getString(R.string.categories_url);

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAGC, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            Category c = new Category();

                            JSONObject jsonObjectData = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            // extract the id
                            c.setId(jsonObjectData.getInt("id"));

                            // extract the name
                            c.setName(jsonObjectData.getString("name"));

                            //extract the parent
                            c.setParent(jsonObjectData.getInt("parent"));

                            //extract the parent
                            c.setCount(jsonObjectData.getInt("count"));

                            cat_list.add(c);
                            extractPosts(i); //here I call the function to extract the posts

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    MySingletonVolley.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

}


public void extractPosts(int i) {
    int cont = 0;
    String URL = getResources().getString(R.string.posts_url);

        int cant_post_real = this.cat_list.get(i).getCount(); 
        int page = 0;
        while ( cant_post_real > 0) {
            page++;
            String complete_url = URL + page + "&categories=" + this.cat_list.get(i).getId(); 

            JsonArrayRequest request1 = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, complete_url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
                            for (int k = 0; k < response.length(); k++) {
                                try {
                                    Post p = new Post();

                                    JSONObject jsonObjectData = response.getJSONObject(k);

                                    // extract the title
                                    JSONObject titleObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("title");
                                    p.setTitle(titleObject.getString("rendered"));

                                    // extract the content
                                    JSONObject contentObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("content");
                                    p.setContent(contentObject.getString("rendered"));

                                    //extract the excerpt
                                    JSONObject excerptObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                                    p.setExcerpt(excerptObject.getString("rendered"));

                                    // extract feature image
                                    JSONObject embeddedObject = jsonObjectData.getJSONObject("_embedded");
                                    JSONArray wpfeaturemediaArray = embeddedObject.getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia");
                                    JSONObject firstElement = wpfeaturemediaArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    p.setFeature_image(firstElement.getString("source_url"));

                                    posts.add(p);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }


                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            cant_post_real = cant_post_real - 10;
            MySingletonVolley.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(request1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say it doesn't return a value, what does it do?  Is either the onError or onResponse called?  If not, are you sure the request went out (Volley was properly started)?  If onError is called, what's the error?  If onResponse, step through and see where your parsing is broken.

Comment: Also, I'd highly consider swapping from Volley to Retrofit.  Volley has some issues with threading and large responses due to the way the API works, and its a much more complicated API to work with.

Comment: In debugging, the value that request1 takes is this,  request1=[ ] https://domainx/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&page=1&categories=2583 0xd547dcfa NORMAL null,  but I put this url in the browser and it gives me a response with values, thanks for your reply